# Encoding string in order to Insert SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlcommand

I'm using sqlite3_exec() function in order to execute an SQL Insert command. The problem starts when I need to insert strings that need to be encoded.

For example, I want to insert the following string: "f('hello')". If I want to insert this string I need to change "'" to "''".

My question is, how do I encode these strings? Is there a function I can count on? or a table that details all the needed encodes?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manually escaping strings (which is error-prone and invites SQL injection attacks), I'd strongly recommend using prepared statements and bind values; read up on sqlite3_bind_XXX and [sqlite3_prepare_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using bind values will solve this problem and it will also make sqlite faster because it remembers previously executed sql statements and it can reuse their execution plans. This doesn't work when the sql statement is always slightly different because it hashes the complete sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite_mprintf` supports `%q` for that.

Answer (score 0):

"Maybe" you should use something like a prepared statement. I am not an expert in SQLite, but I found this link (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) and it could help you. It is about SQL Statement Object.